# What does "wishing I hadn't than end up wishing I had" mean?

Tags: meaning

Countess Vronskaya says to Anna Karenina:

> Countess Vronskaya: My sons are ashamed of me. But I'd rather end up
> **wishing I hadn't than end up wishing I had**.

What does "wishing I hadn't than end up wishing I had" mean?

Comment: There is some  missing participle. wish I had [done, gone, seen, etc], wishing I had [done, gone, seen] or some other verb that describes what is going on. This is completely grammatical in English but we can't tell what is meant without what was written before this.

Comment: It probably relates to the amorous adventures that Countess "Vronsky" (Vronskaya) had in her youth. Better, as many sayings have it, to regret having loved, than to regret not having loved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what action the Countess is contemplating; presumably something rather daring. She says that she would rather do it, even at the risk of regretting it later, than not do it and later regret not having done so.

Comment: It's what she did long ago in her youth, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine someone says "Do you want to do a bungee jump?"

If you say "Yes", and you don't enjoy it, then you "end up wishing that you hadn't done a bungee jump".

If you say "No", then you don't do the jump and you might "end up wishing that you had done a bungee jump".

So:

> Do you want to do a bungee jump?
>
> Yes. Because I'd rather end up wishing I hadn't, than wishing I had.

This is the "fear of missing out".

Now I'm sure that the Countess isn't going to do a bungee jump.  But she is going to do something that will shock and embarrass her sons.